# IBDesignable controls in a framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibdesignable

I've watched the excellent video on IBDesignable https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-411/ and have created a framework with a control in, to be used by my main app (and shared, if necessary).

I've created a custom 'composite' control using IB, as per this great tutorial, http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

The technique works well and I can now place my designable controls on my storyboard.

The problem is that I notice that all my IBOutlets and IBActions in my 'framework' appear in IB on my storyboard. But I wish to hide them! The functionality for the controls is hidden within the framework and the IBOutlets and IBActions have been created as such to facilitate their operation within that framework, with notification to the outside-world being handled via delegates or some other means.

This technique is compelling in that I can use it to create a reusable library of 'composite' controls but it would be useful to hide certain IBOutlets and IBActions from the library's implementors to ensure an element of 'security'

Can this be done? 
Are there any flags to hide IBOutlet/IBAction elements within the framework?

Answer (score 0):

When you speak of security, if you declare of @IBActions, @IBOutlets etc... as Internal, then they're private to your App's module.

In terms of frameworks, they consist of their own module (check in build settings, Module Name) and make sure "defines module" is enabled.

This ensures that your module is for starters "enabled" i.e. everything in your Framework (or app, or bundle which have their own modules defined) have their own environment.

From there, make sure that you've used the correct privacy when it comes to declarations:

Access control is explained is better detail here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. I should have said that I'm coding the framework in Objective-C. This will probably make a difference to the accessibility and visibility. I'm wondering if there's a way?